# Counting all the number in a 2d array

Tags: c++

I want to count all the numbers in a 2d array and store the count into another array so can I can use the values in a histogram equalization.I am counting values that range from 0 to 255, so everytime a number for example 18 comes up in the 2d array I want to count how many 18's there are in the 2d array and then store the count into num[17]. Problem is I don't get the right amount. I know is due to the temp not being in the right place but I cannot figure out where to put it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>




void histeq(int **pix, int height, int width) {

int num[255];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= 255; k++)

        {

            if (pix[i][j] == k)
            {
                temp = temp + 1;
            }
            num[k - 1] = temp;
            cout << num[k - 1] << endl;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: is it important to use an array to store numbers. you can use a map. that would be better.

Comment: No it's not important, that is just a way I thought of in order to not have clutter of values, since its a lot of numbers. Also I never used a map so I don't know how they work.

Comment: [No time like the present to learn.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). a `std::map<int,int> histogram;` will reduce a lot of the counting to `histogram[pix[i][j]]++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your expectation. You mean you want to count how many time number of arange[0:255] in 2d Array:

```
#include <iostream>

void histeq(int **pix, int height, int width) {

int num[255];

for (int k =1; k <= 255; k++)
{
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        if (pix[i][j] == k)
        {
            temp +=1;
        }
   }
}
num[k - 1] = temp;
cout << num[k - 1] << endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear form your question, but my best guess is that you need this:

```
void histeq(int **pix, int height, int width) {

    int num[256] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            num[pix[i][j]] += 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        cout << num[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <map>
void histeq(int **pix, int height, int width) {

std::map <int, int> num;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        num[pix[i][j]]++;    
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
    cout << num[i] <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Although this was not what I was looking I can use this code to make a histogram which is still good thanks. I reworded the question to make better sense of what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion